# how to pass an hierarchical array through command line to a php file

Tags: php, arrays, command-line

I want to pass an array from command line to php as:

```
c:\<path>\php.exe somefile.php --filter array{['name']=>"lion",['category']=>array{['teeth']=>'long_teeth',['height']=>'short'}}
```

and now in code I want variable filter as an array as I passed through command line like:

```
$opt['filter'] = array {
                    ['name']=>"lion",
                    ['category']=>
                        array{
                              ['teeth']=>'long_teeth',
                              ['height']=>'short'
                             }
                       }
```

But the problem is passed argument becomes string and I am not able to parse it to array.
I am using getopt() function to get filter as an attribute to array variable $opt like:

```
$shortopts = "abc"; // These options do not accept values

$longopts  = array(
    "filter:",     // Required value
);<br>
$opt = getopt($shortopts, $longopts);
```

actually whole scenario is to take a variable as an array or string or a boolean value and pass it to another php script as it is and that script I am calling through exec function like:
`exec(c:\<path>\php.exe myphpscript.php --filter $array_variable );` 
and then in myphpscript.php, I want to use `$array_variable` as it was in earlier script so that I can use it as it was.

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are strings and only strings.

As you want to pass in a hierarchical element the only option is to parse the string. However JSON encoding is nice, easy and compact.

Passing the following on the command line and then parsing with [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) will give you the required results;

```
{"Name":"Lion","Category":{"teeth":"long_teeth","height":"short"}}
```

simple proof:

```
$opt = '{"Name":"Lion","Category":{"teeth":"long_teeth","height":"short"}}';
print_r(json_decode($opt));
```

Comment: but it prints as stdclass object and I want to get my passed string back as array object so that i can access $opt['Name'] and $opt['Category']['height'] for other usage.

Comment: $opt = "{'Name':'Lion','Category':{'teeth':'long_teeth','height':'short'}}"; doesn't work with print_r(json_decode($opt))

Comment: That's because you are using the wrong quotes; unlike PHP and JavaScript the quotes aren't interchangeable JSON requires the " to identify strings, ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments can only be strings, there's no way to pass any complex data structures like arrays directly on the command line. You can *serialize* an array into a string though and *unserialize* that argument in your program. So you can pass an array around as a string. The most obvious candidate is the JSON format, see [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode).